# Where did HttpProviders go in IAppHost?

Tags: servicestack

I'm having problems in a project that runs on the v3.9.0.0 version of servicestack.
So I'm trying to download source for it. But on github there are no tags so it seems I cant get hold of the source. So... I downloaded the latest stack and the source for that.

Obviously I'm getting some deprecated warnings but except for that the compiler seems happy enough except for in one place

```
public virtual void Configure(IAppHost appHost, Container container)
{
        appHost.HtmlProviders.Add(new HtmlProvider().ProcessRequest);
```

The compiler complains that IAppHost does not have a property HtmlProviders

Like so:

`ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.IAppHost` does not contain a definition for `HtmlProviders` and no extension method 'HtmlProviders' accepting a first argument of type `ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.IAppHost` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I can't find anyone mentioning this missing so I'm guessing I'm missing something but what.
So at the end I guess the questions are:

- Does anyone know how to get the source for the v3.9.0.0 version of servicestack?
- Does anyone know what to do to migrate from v3.9.0.0 to current 3.x version considering the above HtmlProviders problem?

(I edited this post as I misread the version number at first)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking history for IAppHost your probably looking for roughly [v3.94](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/tree/6a993646638a853bf3f91bd484d80795724aa303), about 10 months ago. How to upgrade to latest version? I'd suggest migrating a single service to the new API and going from there.

Comment: Thanx Gavin for checking this up. I got that source down but I guess it's not in stable state. I got a bunch of warnings as errors do I removed that in the test projects. Then it builds ok. But then I'm trying to do the build.bat for nuget and it all goes a bit wrong. Missing folder paths and references to folder above the source root like the reference to the chaweet folder :-) Im working my way though it but Im wondering if there is a point. I'm kind of missing tags so I could get the latest "stable" version where IAppHost was not broken.

Comment: As to migration, what I really ment was: what do I do instead of assigning to HtmlProviders in the IAppHost interface? From the code I'm guessing that HtmlProviders got replaced by ViewEngines. Only trouble is that ViewEnginges is 'get' only. So... what to do instead?

Comment: Just remove the HtmlProviders assignment. The new API uses Plugins to register ViewEngines in AppHost now, e.g. `Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());`.I'd still suggest starting a new project and migrating a single service to the new API, I'm not that familiar with the old version and have no idea what else is a breaking change.

Comment: And the HtmlProvider is now enabled by default. See here for more info. https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Plugins

Comment: Hi Gavin, well... I tried tho remove the HtmlProviders assignment. And as you suspected there is a lot more that breaks. So I fall back to get a source version for the 3.9.0.0 that this project originally was using. I got source for soething that seems to be 3.9.4 but then It seems it got dependancies on ServiceStack.Text (witch ofcourse seems to be the place where the exception originates) So I got the source for that to but now ServiceStack.Common and ServiceStack.Text collides in extensions. So I'm back in not beeing able to get a stable coherent version of what was 3.9.0.0 to build from.